# jsTree Default Arrow/Triangle Icon Configuration

Tags: jquery, html, css, jstree

Good afternoon,

I'm relatively new to using the jsTree plugin and am trying to better understand how to configure the default arrow/triangle icon that will change directions depending on whether a particular node has any child nodes. I'm applying the jsTree plugin to a basic HTML un-ordered list and I'm fine either disabling the default arrow/triangle icons altogether or replacing them with custom images. The documentation on the jsTree site only touches upon changing the icons in lieu of the default folder icons for list items so any help on this front is greatly appreciated.

Best,

Wyattburp86